# Import python packages like NumPy or Pandas in imported modules

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I have a main Python-program called `mainProgram.py`. It looks like this (simplified example):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from packOne import functionOne
from packTwo import functionTwo

ResultOne = functionOne()
ResultTwo = functionTwo()
```

File `__init__.py` was also created.

After running the main program `mainProgram.py` I received NameError:

```
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

In package `PackOne.py` I use some functions from `NumPy`, but I didn't import `NumPy` in the package `PackOne.py`. Should I also import `NumPy` in `packOne` and all other packages which I'm going to import? Are there any elegant solutions, how to import packages like `NumPy` or `Pandas` once in main python program?

Comment: A package is meant to be independent of the main. You have to explicit all the packages used for every file of your package.

Comment: @Kefeng91 do you mean, I have to import all necessary packages (like Numpy and Pandas) in all my private packages, which I will import in main program?

Comment: Yes, you have to import numpy inside packOne if functions inside packOne use it.  You ask "Are there any elegant solutions, how to import packages like NumPy or Pandas once in main python program?" which is a reasonable question but the answer is probably no.  The idea, as Kefeng91 say, is to have packages be independent of any main program or other packages they may be used by. So they do their own imports and don't share.  If the main program had to import all the packages used by all the other packages any large application might have hundreds of (possibly conflicting) imports.

Comment: @Ymareth thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Ymareth: This should be an answer and accepted.